# About Java EE, Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

Basically I want to learn this technology. I already know Java SE. My question is, what is a good start to learn Spring and Hibernate? Is the book Head First JSP and Servlets good or what?

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, where is the good start to learn Spring and Hibernate?

I'd recommend the Second of Edition of [Spring in Action](http://www.manning.com/walls3/) by Craig Wall (it covers both) and of course the [Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) of Spring Framework.

> Is the book Head First JSP and Servlets good or what?

It is. But not for the mentioned topics.

Comment: In addition to these books I would highly recommend picking up 'Harnessing Hibernate' as well. Its a great into to Hibernate and complements the other books quite well.
The Hibernate tutorial is also quite helpful if you don't want to buy a book:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There are many topics under the Spring framework. The ones that I use most are - IOC, AOP, Transaction Management, and Spring JDBC. In order to grasp these concepts I used the spring website extensively and also read the [Spring Recipe](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590599799)s book. I coded the examples that were on the book and tried to convert an existing app in using the spring framework (like IOC and JDBC). The spring forum is very useful. An of course folks here at Stack Overflow are always willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

I could recommend you [Pro Spring 2.5](http://apress.com/book/view/9781590599211) by Rob Harrop and Jan Machacek. It's quite easy to read and there are quite a lot of simple, but precise examples. And, of course, Spring has [very good reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

And if you want to know more about Hibernate, you should definetely take a look at [Java Persistence with Hibernate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394885). One of the author is Gavin King, creator of Hibernate, so while reading this book you're getting first hand knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The spring [latest documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) is the good start for learning spring.

Since, spring has so many modules, you may initially get confused.
you can start spring core and can learn the rest of the modules as you go further.